# Safari refreshes the page on setting 'animation-play-state' to paused

Tags: javascript, css, animation, browser, safari

This is really weird, but each time I set `$(element).css('animation-play-state', 'paused');` safari refreshes the whole page.

Why?

Comment: Which version of Safari are you using?

Comment: The latest, a fresh install on windows 8: 5.1.7

Comment: Then it uses hardware acceleration and you might solve the issue with adding: `-webkit-transform: translate3d(X,Y,Z);`

Comment: That actually makes WebKit2WebProcess.exe crash each time, and it still refreshes the page.

Comment: Good grief. Sounds like there's a nasty bug in Safari.

Comment: Are you using safari? Can you test it: http://tonybogdanov.com/phoci you should see animating circles, each time there comes a new "tick" (e.g. each second) the page refreshes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22178/discussion-between-kyle-sevenoaks-and-tony)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a bug in Safari 5.1 (maybe higher as well.) that the program is trying to access a part of protected memory that it should not be and Windows stops the process before it makes any major problems. [A whole lot of bug reports have been submitted to Apple](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3194268?start=0&tstart=0), but there is no word of a fix yet.

You can try repairing the install of Safari, but it's anyone's guess as to whether it will work or not and of course, other users on your page will have to go through these steps which is a lot to ask them.

```
Windows + R -> appwiz.cpl -> Right click Safari -> Repair.
```

Hope some of that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm encountering the same issue with Safari 5.1.7 on Windows, but when executing the same code on a Mac using Safari 5.0.6, it works without issue.

Unfortunately can't conclude weather it's Windows, or anything above Safari 5.1 as @Kramp suggested. Would assume Windows..